# creating title page in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm working with Latex Beamer for my first time and I have a question regarding my title page. At the moment, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to delete the grey box around my title and also the headline, but only on my titlepage, not on the other slides.

Does anybody know how this might work?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Kathi

Here is my working example (at the moment I still try to modify the layout, so I have almost no content):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Dresden} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\author{K} 
\title{Title} 
\date{\today} 
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
%\date{} 
%\subject{} 

\begin{document}
    %\begin{frame} %\tableofcontents %\end{frame}

    \frame{\titlepage}

    \begin{frame} \frametitle{\"Ubersicht} \tableofcontents \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction} 

\begin{frame}{Introduction} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item Illokution 
\item Searle 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 

\section{Theoretical Background} 
\begin{frame}{Theoretical Background} IFID\ Gestik 
\end{frame} 

\section{Experiment} 
\begin{frame}{Experiment} 
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} 

\subsection{Hpothesis} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} \subsection{Methods} 
\begin{frame} {Methode} 
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} 

\subsection{Participants} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} 

\section{Results} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame}\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame} 

\section{Discussion} 
\begin{frame} {test} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, this is completely unrelated to title pages with beamer, but the content might still interest or at least amuse you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- to remove the headline either use the `plain` option for this frame (this will remove the footline as well) or temporarily set the the headline template to empty.
- to remove the grey box, set the title background colour either to empty or to white.
- Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Dresden} 
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{graphicx} 

\author{K} 
\title{Title} 
\date{\today} 

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}    

\begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}     
\endgroup   

\end{document}
```