# How can I vertically center heading of Frame?

Tags: beamer, vertical

So, as the title says my goal is to vertically center the title of a frame. The frame is the first one of a subsection.  I only want to display the title and nothing else. The problem seems trivial, but I could not find any solution for it. First of all some example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t,usepdftitle=false,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{My Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which creates this slide:
[image]

I only want to move the title like this:

[image]

Important is also that it should only affect this slide and no other slides. I would like something that moves the title. Another solution I thought of would be to copy the title style and insert normal text in the center of the frame. Unfortunately, I could not achieve any working solution. Therefore, I would be very glad for any help!

Comment: It is not clear, what you after. I guess that you looking for `\titlepage`, see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399773/ , if this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to change the titlepage only want to center the frametitle on one particular slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}
\author{JANO}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue}

\begin{frame}
Some frame content (without frame title)
\end{frame}

\author{}
\title{My Title}
\date{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
Some frame content (without frame title)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is not exactly what I wanted, but very very close. I tested it and it is not vertically centered but still looks good in my opinion. So, I think I will stick with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

helps to center within the first line. I'm not sure about centering within the frame honestly. good luck with your work.